# Django: default value for select element in django form

Tags: django

Let's say I have a model and a form:

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SelectIndustryForm(ModelForm):
    industry = ModelChoiceField(label='Industry', required=True, queryset=Industry.objects.all(),
                                 widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select', 'name': 'industry'}))
```

I created a bunch of objects of the Industry class, and among them there is an object with the title "Unspecified". Is it possible to make this option a default value in the HTML select element (the one where you need to choose an option in the drop-down list) when the form loads?

Comment: In your view, you'll need to first retrieve that special `Industry` instance and then you can use the `initial` argument when you instantiate your `SelectIndustryForm` form

Answer (score 2):

In your view you could do this like this:

```
def your_view(request):
    unspecified_industry = Industry.objects.get(title="unspecified")
    form = SelectIndustryForm(initial={"industry": unspecified_industry})
    ....
```